# Displaying results with quick consecutive AJAX calls

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Just so you can visualize it better, I've got a PHP script for a Hotel Management application that displays a calendar (table columns: days of the month / lines: prices per day).

I can access this script in edit mode, which creates a small  element inside each .

When I change the value of the  field, an ajaxcall does the background job and returns the updated value back to the  field (to confirm that the new value is updated in the database).

When I change values slowly (more than 1 second per field), it works perfectly. But when I try to speed it up (edit value, TAB to the next field, change value, and so on..) the ajaxcall updates the database but it fails to update back the  field.

Any ideas about why is this happening? And how to fix it?
I have tried it in all browsers.

HTML part:

```
<td>
    <input type='text' id='$counter' onChange='updateAvailability(this,$idroomclass,\"$date\",$counter)'
    value='$total' />
</td>
```

Javascript:

```
function ajaxRequest() {
    try {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    } catch (e1) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (e2) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e3) {
                request = false
            }
        }
    }
    return request
}

function updateAvailability(vagos, idroomclass, date, input_id) {
    if (vagos.value != "") {
        params = "vagos=" + vagos.value + "&idroomclass=" + idroomclass + "&date=" + date
        request = new ajaxRequest()
        request.open("POST", "ajaxcalls/updateAvailability.php", true)
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
        request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById(input_id).value = request.responseText;
                } else alert("Ajax error: " + this.statusText)
            }
        }
        request.send(params)
    }
}
```

Comment: Difficult to tell without an example. Can you set something up on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider the overall algorithm.

As I understand you are trying to create an web application that allows concurrent modification of data (in this case: a calender entry).

This could be solved by the sort of algorithms used for concurrently editing text documents (e.g. Google Docs) - but that's probably overkill here.

I'd suggest to use an approach with local locking:
Once the user clicks into that element an AJAX call requires from the server a "lease" for modifying that element. The server will respond with a message that tells the client that it's currently locked (-> the user can't modify it) or tell the client that it's now allowed to modify it's content - all other clients would now get back a locked messages when they try to modify it.
Then on the client you can write whatever you want (till a timeout).
Once you leave that element again the client sends the server a message with the new content and the information that it's now unlocked again.

If you need live updates on other clients as well, you could send the current content by a timer.

Comment: To be honest, as my knowledge of AJAX and Javascript is not that advanced, I hope I am making a simple mistake, like using the wrong way to update the <input> from within the AJAX call.
If there's no quick fix, I would just create a javascript to disable all other <input> fields, until the AJAX call updates the current <INPUT> that triggered the call.